# How to modify results from a read-only ng-app?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, class, angularjs-ng-app

I apologize if this is a duplicate, just haven't been able to find anything close to this myself.

The company I work for has an online reporting system that is run by an ng-app applied directly to the body tag. I have been tasked with modifying the result that returns from this ng-app. Following code is called using onload attached to the body tag.

```js
function getElements(){
  var list;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("neutral");
  [].forEach.call(list, function (listItem) {
       addNeutral(listItem);
  });

...
```

Basically, trying to find anything with class "neutral" and apply results from another function to it. The addNeutral function is basically just

```js
element.classList.add("neutralHighlight");
```

This code seems to run and gathers the correct list of elements, but the new class is never added and no errors occur. So long story short, is there any way to modify the output of a ng-app using code separate from the ng-app itself? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 3/5/20

So I implemented Shaun's response and it still isn't working properly. With some debug messages, I can see that it collects the "list" variable as an HTMLCollection. The forEach function doesn't seem to even trig

```js
function getElements(){
  var list;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("neutral");
  console.log(list); //Debug - Shows in console
  [].forEach.call(list, function (listItem) {
       console.log(listItem); //Debug - Does not show in console
       addNeutral(listItem);
  });
  }
  
  function addNeutral(element){
    angular.element(element).addClass("neutralHighlight"); 
    console.log("!!!end addNeutral"); //Debug - Does not show in console
  }
```

### Update 3/9/20 -SOLUTION-

Application is returning the HTML Collection, but it displays with a length of 0 (still displays the objects, but I think that's a Firefox console thing). When trying to loop through the list items, it returns null for the first item, so the function is still being called before the Angular app loads completely.

That being said, I messed around with things a bit this morning and came to a solution! I ended up using the setInterval function with a 5 second interval (since I need it to update, I may change this to optimize it later by adding onChange items to the objects I grab initially). The setTimeout that was proposed would have worked with a delay added to it. This probably isn't the most elegant solution, and there's probably a better way to do it, but this works for anyone interested.

```js
function getElements(){
  var list;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("neutral");
  for (i = 0; i <= list.length; i++){
    var listItem = list.item(i);
    addNeutral(listItem);
  }
}

function loadFunction(){
  setInterval(function(){getElements()}, 5000);
}
```

I added `<script>loadFunction()</script>` right before the closing HTML tag to execute.

### Update 4/21/20 -IMPROVED SOLUTION- CSS Attributes

So this is a bit specific to my scenario, but I wanted to include it for anybody else who may come across this in the future. I was actually able to accomplish this entirely with CSS attribute selectors. The tags that I wanted to edit all had specific titles assigned to them via the ng-app provided from the company, so I was able to use CSS selectors like `div [title~="NotReadyForNextCall"]{<custom styling here>}` to select any block that included an agent who was not ready for their next call. This is a much better solution in terms of resources required to operate and overall performance, so I hope it helps anybody looking at this down the line!

Comment: AngularJS is a DOM manipulation framework and, in general, you will find that attempting to manipulate the DOM of an AngularJS app from outside the framework troublesome. That being said, I'm a little surprised that manipulating the class is not working. I suspect AngularJS may be coming up behind your changes and overwriting them in some way. It's hard to say for sure either way without seeing the AngularJS app.

Comment: Lex, thanks for the explanation on AngularJS. I wish I could paste some code from the AngularJS app, but it's all proprietary and I'd probably get fired/get the company sued. I don't know too much about the AngularJS app itself other than the fact that it refreshes its data every 10 seconds. That being said, the changes still don't show before the 10 seconds loop. I'll update with any new findings.

Comment: The `forEach` is likely not executing because the list is empty. Add `console.log("length", list.length);` to your debugging. An AngularJS app that fetches data from a server will wait for the data to arrive from the server before adding DOM elements to display that data. And if it fetches data every 10 seconds, it will modify the DOM every 10 seconds.

Comment: I updated my answer below to explain a little about using setInterval. Ultimately, now that you have access to the AngularJS app, you should reconsider this entire approach, but it's a helpful question and answer to leave up for someone else looking for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunE.Tobias! Yeah I'll have to see. The only issue is that the Angular app will get modified with every update. The custom js/css won't be touched, which makes it more stable in the long run. If I can figure out a single line or two to add to the end of the Angular to call the function after creation, that will be my approach, but we shall see. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get around this by using the `angular` object in your code and adding the class on an `angular.element` instead. AngularJS doesn't use a virtual DOM but it does use its own node references (which is what makes it so tricky to work with outside of the framework, as Lex pointed out in the comments of your question). Try:

```
angular.element(element).addClass("neutralHighlight");
```

Yes, you have access to `angular` outside of the app! And a last note, `addClass()` is available on `angular.element` because AngularJS comes with jqLite.

---

**Further investigation**

It looks like the above solution works if the class 'neutral' is being added in angular via the `class` attribute, but it looks like your app may be adding it programmatically with the `ng-class` directive after the DOM has rendered.

I wrapped your `getElements()` function in a `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(getElements);
```

This is unfortunately not a guarantee that the `ng-class` update will have taken place, but what it does is it executes the function after the previous digest cycle has completed and that appears to be working.

An even safer solution would be to use `document.ready` but again with the `angular.element` wrapper. This will ensure the initial DOM state has been rendered by AngularJS, including applied directives:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  getElements();
});
```

**EDIT: Update 3/9/20 -SOLUTION-**

The solution proposed in the answer is almost identical to the `setTimeout()` answer given here. The only difference is `setInterval()` will keep executing the code every 5 seconds until you tell it to stop.

You can do this with the following:

```
var loadFunction = setInterval(function() {
  var el = getElements();
  if (el) clearInterval(loadFunction);
}, 5000);
```

And just return a bool in your `getElements()` like so:

```
function getElements() {
  var list;
  var found = false;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("neutral");
  [].forEach.call(list, function (listItem) {
       addNeutral(listItem);
       found = true;
  });
  return found;
}
```

See: [codepen.io/shaunetobias/pen/KKpXRxq](https://codepen.io/shaunetobias/pen/KKpXRxq)

Comment: Thanks for the response! It still isn't working, but I added the code in an update above for you to check if it's implemented properly. If you could check and see if it's correct, that would be amazing.

Comment: It looks like my solution works if the class 'neutral' is being added in angular via the `class` attr, but it looks like your app may be adding it with the `ng-class` directive. I wrapped your `getElements()` function in a `setTimeout()`. This is unfortunately not a guarantee that the ng-class update will have taken place, but what it does is it executes the function after the previous digest cycle has completed and that appears to be working. Check: https://codepen.io/shaunetobias/pen/KKpXRxq if it does the job, I can update my answer above.

Comment: I updated the answer with an even safer solution. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: The AngularJS framework waits for  "ready" before bootstrapping itself. Any DOM manipulation by the framework will not be done until well after "ready". If it fetches data or templates from the server, there will be more delay.

Comment: Also true. Depending on when those classes are applied, what's trying to be achieved might not be plausible.

Comment: So I did try wrapping the function with the .ready functions as recommended by @ShaunE.Tobias and the only difference now is that it returns the HTMLCollection object twice onLoad. Sorry for the delayed responses, this project is one of many going on currently. I'll look more into Angular, but any other ideas or recommendations? I gained access to the AngularJS code. Can I call an external js function at the end of the Angular code to scan the result that way? Thanks for your help so far everyone!

Comment: Worked with it a bit more this morning. Looks like it is still trying to access the DOM before it is loaded, which makes the "list" HTML Collection come through with a length of 0, even though the console itself shows all of the objects in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as suggested above, it looks like those classes are added by the `ngClass` directive which is applied after an unknown amount of time/number of digests. I will leave this answer here as it could be helpful to others who might have this unorthodox task. If you gained access to the AngularJS, you should find where the `neutral ` classes are being added then just add the new classes there.